# Matlab finding the center of cluster of a few pixels and counting the clusters

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, image-processing, matrix

So I have this matrix A, which is made of 1 and zeros, I have about 10 to 14 white spots of many pixels, but I want only 1 white pixel/centers coordinate for every cluster of white, how do I calculate how many cluster there are and their centers.

Try to imagine the matrix A as the night sky with white starts in black sky and how to I count the stars and the stars centers, plus the star are made of cluster of white pixels.

also the clusters are not all exactly the same size.

Comment: I was thinking if I did some type of sweep ie for every 5 by 5 pixels, and if the sum of each 5 by 5 box is greater than a threshold it would be a centre point, hence place a 1 there, and else everything else zeros

Comment: example image would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code using [bwlabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) and/or regioprops, which are used to identify connected components in a matrix and a buch of other properties, respectively. I think it suits your problem quite well; however you might want to adapt my code a bit as its more of a starting point.

```
clear
clc

%// Create dummy matrix.
BW = logical ([ 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
                1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
                1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
                0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
                0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
                1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
                1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
                1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0]);
        
%// Identify clusters.
L = bwlabel(BW,4)
```

Matrix L looks like this:

```
L =

     1     1     1     0     3     3     3     0
     1     1     1     0     3     3     3     0
     1     1     1     0     3     3     3     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     4     4     0
     2     2     2     2     0     4     4     0
     2     2     2     2     0     4     4     0
     2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0
```

Here you have many ways to locate the center of the clusters. The first one uses the output of bwlabel to find each cluster and calculate the coordinates in a loop. It works and its didactic but it's a bit long and not so efficient. The 2nd method, as mentioned by @nkjt, uses regionprops which does exactly what you want using the 'Centroid' property. So here are the 2 methods:

**Method 1**: a bit complicated
So bwlabel identified 4 clusters, which makes sense. Now we need to identify the center of each of those clusters. My method could probably be simplified; but I'm a bit out of time so fell free to modify it as you see fit.

```
%// Get number of clusters
NumClusters = numel(unique(L)) -1;

Centers = zeros(NumClusters,2);
CenterLinIdices = zeros(NumClusters,1);

for k = 1:NumClusters
    
%// Find indices for elements forming each cluster.
    [r, c] = find(L==k);
    
%// Sort the elements to know hot many rows and columns the cluster is spanning.
    [~,y] = sort(r);
    c = c(y);
    r = r(y);
    
    NumRow = numel(unique(r));
    NumCol = numel(unique(c));
    
%// Calculate the approximate center of the cluster.
    CenterCoord = [r(1)+floor(NumRow/2) c(1)+floor(NumCol/2)];
    
%// Actually this array is not used here but you might want to keep it for future reference.
    Centers(k,:) = [CenterCoord(1) CenterCoord(2)];
    
%// Convert the subscripts indices to linear indices for easy reference.
    CenterLinIdices(k) = sub2ind(size(BW),CenterCoord(1),CenterCoord(2));
end

%// Create output matrix full of 0s, except at the center of the clusters.
BW2 = false(size(BW));
BW2(CenterLinIdices) = 1

BW2 =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**Method 2** Using regionprops and the 'Centroid' property.

Once you have matrix L, apply regionprops and concatenate the output to get an array containing the coordinates directly. Much simpler!

```
%// Create dummy matrix.
BW = logical ([ 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
                1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
                1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
                0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
                0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
                1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
                1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
                1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0]);

%// Identify clusters.
L = bwlabel(BW,4)

s = regionprops(L,'Centroid');

CentroidCoord = vertcat(s.Centroid)
```

which gives this:

```
CentroidCoord =

    2.0000    2.0000
    2.5000    7.0000
    6.0000    2.0000
    6.5000    6.0000
```

Which is much simpler and gives the same output once you use floor.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1, but you can make your life much easier using `regionprops` instead.

Comment: Haha yes indeed! I'll propose another solution with regionprops later today thanks!